# Error: Unable to acquire a connection Knex postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose

I have added a model to my frontend and backend so that users can update their profile (name age etc.), however, when I'm trying to update my test user name it's not updating, and I'm recieving the below error message in my terminal[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf1ky.png)

See below my server.js and profile.js

SERVER.JS

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
const cors = require("cors");
const knex = require("knex");
const register = require("./controllers/register");
const signin = require("./controllers/signin");
const profile = require("./controllers/profile");
const image = require("./controllers/image");
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = "1";

const pool = new Pool({
  connection: process.env.POSTGRES_URI,

  ssl: process.env.DATABASE_URI ? true : false,
});



const db = knex({
  client: "pg",
  connection: process.env.POSTGRES_URI,

  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan("combined"));
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("it is working");
});
app.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
  signin.handleSignin(req, res, db, bcrypt);
});
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt);
});
app.get("/profile/:id", (req, res) => {
  profile.handleProfile(req, res, db);
});
app.post("/profile/:id", (req, res) => {
  profile.handleProfileUpdate(req, res, db);
});
app.put("/image", (req, res) => {
  image.handleImage(req, res, db);
});
app.post("/imageurl", (req, res) => {
  image.handleApiCall(req, res);
});
app.post("/sendResetPassowrdLink", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  pool.query(`SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='${email}'`).then((data) => {
    if (data.rowCount === 0) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ message: "user with that email does not exists" });
    }
    const { email } = data.rows[0];
    const emailBody = `your sever url is http://localhost:3001/resetpassword/${btoa(
      email
    )}`;
    res.send(emailBody);
  });
});
app.get("/resetpassword/:token", (req, res) => {
  const email = atob(req.params.token);
  const { newPassowrd, newPassowrdConfirm } = req.body;
  if (newPassowrd !== newPassowrdConfirm) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "passowrd does not match" });
  }
  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(newPassowrd);
  pool
    .query(`UPDATE login SET hash='${hash}' WHERE email='${email}'`)
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.rowCount === 1) {
        return res
          .status(200)
          .json({ message: "password updated successfully" });
      }
    });
});



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3005;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

PROFILE.JS

```
const handleProfile = (req, res, db) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  db.select("*")
    .from("users")
    .where({ id })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.length) {
        res.json(user[0]);
      } else {
        res.status(400).json("not found");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("error getting user"));
};

const handleProfileUpdate = (req, res, db) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { name, age, pet } = req.body.formInput;
  db("users")
    .where({ id })
    .update({ name })
    .then((resp) => {
      if (resp) {
        res.json("success");
      } else {
        res.status(400).json("Unable to udpate");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

module.exports = {
  handleProfile,
  handleProfileUpdate,
};
```

I also recently added docker container to my backend and database, could that be the cause for the issue?

below is my github backend repo with the docker included
https://github.com/Moshe844/smartbrain-api/tree/master